# Mobile Xpage dojo error, cannot find dojo version 1.9.4

Tags: dojo, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

My iOS and Android apps use 2 mobile Xpages. I had issues when iOS 8.0 came out, and had to install dojo 1.9.4 on our server.

Today for some reason the 2 mobile Xpages cannot find dojo.

When I open the Mobile Xpage in Chrome I get the following error:[image]

But it appears to me that dojo is in the correct place:

[image]

When I check for my dojo version in an Xpage with

```
com.ibm.xsp.context.DojoLibraryFactory.getDefaultLibrary().getVersion()
```

in a computed field I get 1.9.4.

Our server is version 9.0.1.

Over the weekend we installed the latest version of the ExtLib (16) and the OpenNTF ODA extension and rebooted then server.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any fix packs installed?

Comment: No. I think I should upgrade the server. But it is not my decision to make, but I can influence it. Understand that FP2 or so fixed the dojo issue.

Comment: OK I did get the ok to upgrade, will upgrade tonight to 9.0.1 FP5.